# Cumulative sum with conditions

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I tried to get cumulative sums throught column `week` (and if is possible, then get result ordered by column `Datum$ADTE`) in my query:

```
select
      A.Castka "Amount",
      'Cashflow' as N,
      A.Datum$DATE "Datum",
      cast(A.Rok as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(A.Tyden as varchar(4)) "Week"
  from iGateCashflow A
  where
     1 = 1
      and A.BusTransaction_ID = '1D00000101'
      and A.Vyjasneno = 'A'
      and cast(datepart(week ,convert(date, dbo.ib_DateToString(Napocteno$DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 104)) as varchar(4))
              =     44
```

In `where` clause are conditions, whichs will be edited througt external form.

I would like to get result like this (better without `Amount` column)

```
week      N     Amount      Result
44    Cashflow    150          150
45    Cashflow    200          350
46    Cashflow    300          650
47    Cashflow    350          1000
```

I tried something like this, but I can't achieve my expected result:

```
select
    sum(y.Amount),
    Y.N,
    Y.Week
from (
    select
        A.Castka "Amount",
        'Cashflow' as N,
        A.Datum$DATE "Datum",
        cast(A.Rok as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(A.Tyden as varchar(4)) "Week"
    from iGateCashflow A
    where
        1 = 1
        and A.BusTransaction_ID = '1D00000101'
        and A.Vyjasneno = 'A'
        and cast(datepart(week ,convert(date, dbo.ib_DateToString(Napocteno$DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 104)) as varchar(4))
                =   44
) X
join (
    select
        A.Castka "Amount",
        'Cashflow' as N,
        cast(A.Rok as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(A.Tyden as varchar(4)) "Week"
    from iGateCashflow A
    where
        1 = 1
        and A.BusTransaction_ID = '1D00000101'
        and A.Vyjasneno = 'A'
        and cast(datepart(week ,convert(date, dbo.ib_DateToString(Napocteno$DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 104)) as varchar(4))
                =   44
    )   Y on Y.Week <= X.Week
group by
    Y.N,
    Y.Week
order by
    Y.Week
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's more your question than what you showed. But use this as an idea (you'll need to add in `WHERE` conditions, etc)

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY [week])
FROM   iGateCashflow
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use OVER Clause to get Sum partition by Week and order by Date, please refer to 
[Over Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189461.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this

```
select
    cast(A.Rok as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(A.Tyden as varchar(4)) "Week",
    sum(B.Castka) "Total amount"
from iGateCashflow A
inner join iGateCashflow B
    on A.BusTransaction_ID = B.BusTransaction_ID
    and A.Vyjasneno = B.Vyjasneno
    and B.week <= A.week --> if week is a calculated field, include the calculation here for both 'week's
where
    1 = 1
    and A.BusTransaction_ID = '1D00000101'
    and A.Vyjasneno = 'A'
    and cast(datepart(week ,convert(date, dbo.ib_DateToString(Napocteno$DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 104)) as varchar(4))
            =   44
group by cast(A.Rok as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(A.Tyden as varchar(4)) "Week"
```